# Select audio device appears every time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, devices

Select Audio Device appears every time, but I'm not disconnecting anything. I select an option and 1 second later the modal appears again, I don't remember changing anything in my settings and **the audio and microphone work perfectly without interruptions**. The only way to stop it is when I leave the audio settings open, as it becomes impossible to use the computer with so much audio pop up appearing.

When I close the settings the modal appears again every second or less.
[image]